# How does SQL Server add the with (nolock) one time and effect all query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I use N tables now, need to add N times `with (nolock)`, for example

```sql
select * from T1  with (nolock)
join T2 with (nolock) ..
join T3 with (nolock) ..
join T4 with (nolock) ..
....
```

If I want to declare it once, what can I make the next all query work `with (nolock)`

like :

```sql
use all with (nolock)
select * from T1
join T2 ..
join T3 ..
join T4 ..
....
```

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that you want your query to read inaccurate data, so I'm surprised you want to use the `NOLOCK` hint.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes,it's report system, so I want to use nolock

Comment: @O_O_Sleep_Nice Maybe, maybe not. It is good to understand nolock (and read uncommited isolation level) and the problems they can cause. [nolock and other poor ideas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davidlean/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas), [bad habits - nolock everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set Transaction isolation level read uncommitted`, e.g:

```
set Transaction isolation level read uncommitted
select * from T1
join T2 ..
join T3 ..
join T4 ..
```

Notice:

> Transactions running at the READ UNCOMMITTED level `do not` issue shared locks to prevent other transactions from modifying data read by the current transaction. READ UNCOMMITTED transactions are also `not blocked` by exclusive locks that would prevent the current transaction from reading rows that have been modified but not committed by other transactions. When this option is set, it is possible to `read uncommitted modifications`, which are called `dirty reads`. Values in the data can be changed and rows can appear or disappear in the data set before the end of the transaction.

from [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)